# select_dtypes(include=['number']) does not select the first column

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading an excel file like so:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:file.xlsx", sheet_name='first')
```

`df`

```
category    1    2    3    4
A           105  200  54   49
B           18   9    8    74
```

```
# then I want to multiply the numbers by a 1000, so I use this
df[df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns] *= 1000
```

`df`

```
category    1    2       3        4
A           105  200000  54000    49000
B           18   9000    8000     74000
```

But it ends up multiplying everything but the first column, then I check if it is `int`:

```
df[df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns]

category      2    3    4
A             200  54   49
B             9    8    74
```

But I am sure that all of the columns are type int:

```
for item in df.columns:
    print(item, type(item))
```

```
category <class 'str'>
1 <class 'int'>
2 <class 'int'>
3 <class 'int'>
4 <class 'int'>
```

So why is `df[df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns]` not selecting the first column?

Comment: This `for item in df.columns:    print(item, type(item))` only checks if column titles are `int`. You should check column value dtypes via `df.info()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First columns is filled by numbers saved like strings, check it by [`DataFrame.dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html):

```
print (df.dtypes)
category    object
1           object
2            int64
3            int64
4            int64
dtype: object
```

Your solution:

```
for item in df.columns:
    print(item, item.dtype)
```

Comment: got it, trying to to use `pd.to_numeric` gives me `ValueError: Unable to parse string "####################################################" at position 173` will look in to that. Any ideas why it may be like this?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - ya, wrong data, in numeric values is `####################################################`, need `df[1] = pd.to_numeric(df[1], errors='coerce')`